# Linked List given ONLY a pointer to a node to be deleted in a singly Linked List (delete code difference)?

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

After I made my TODOs
I know the solution is as below

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) { 
    node.data = (node.next).data; 
    node.next = (node.next).next; 

    System.gc(); 
}
```

But my question is that

How above solution differ than below another one
Is both are valid solutions and make the same functionality or not

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) { 
    node = (node.next); 

    System.gc(); 
}
```

Comment: Note: deleted node should NOT be the last node

Comment: you can check if ( node.next != null ) and dont need to call System.gc(); java got excellent garbage collector which will serve for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @talex

And I visualize the cases to be more clear
Lets assume the problem to delete following `node c` from the Linked List
And *we ONLY have access to this node*
[image]

**First solution** will actually delete the node

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) { 
    node.data = (node.next).data; 
    node.next = (node.next).next; 

    System.gc(); 
}
```

By copy next cell (value and pointer) to the parameter cell
So the end result
Parameter cell will be considered as deleted and Linked List will be chained correctly
Hints:

- No problem that `node d` not used by any pointer, `GC` will clean
- This solution will NOT work if we need to delete the last cell

[image]

**Second solution** will NOT delete the node

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) { 
    node = (node.next); 

    System.gc(); 
}
```

Thats because its ONLY change pointer of the parameter cell
So the end result
Parameter cell will NOT be deleted and Linked List still have the cell
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
node = (node.next);
```

you change parameter, but doesn't change any data.

Java use call by value approach (it slightly difficult to understand what does it mean to pass reference by value).

Here is little example:

```
void foo(int i) {
    i = 2;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

when we call it

```
int j = 1;
foo(j);
System.out.println(j);
```

we get `2` and `1` on console.
It means that when `foo` is called copy of the value passed to it.

PS:

You don't need to call `System.gc();`.